# I am not getting data on to my restful web service using angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services

This is my angular js code in which i want to send data in Json format to my restful web service written in java. It makes call to the webservice but i don't get any data.

```
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myPost", []);
        app.controller("myControl", function ($scope, $http) {

            $scope.title = "",
                    $scope.rating = "",
                    $scope.feedback = "",
                    $scope.role = "";

            $scope.send = function (title, rating, feedback, role) {
                var feed = {
                    title: title,
                    rating: rating,
                    feedback: feedback,
                    role: role
                };
                var head = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'myurl',
                    data: feed,
                    headers: head
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.users = data;
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.error = status;
                });
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myPost" ng-controller="myControl">
    <form action="">
        Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="" ng-model="title" />{{title}}<br>
        Rating:<br> <select name="rating" ng-model="rating">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select><br>
        Feedback: <input type="text" name="feedback" value="" ng-model="feedback"/><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="article" ng-model="role" />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="send(title, rating, feedback, role)" value="submit" />
```

This is my restful Web Service where I want the data.

```
@Path("/database")
public class database {

    @Path("/insert")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String insert(@QueryParam("title") String title,
            @QueryParam("rating") int rating,
            @QueryParam("feedback") String feedback,
            @QueryParam("role") String role) {
        Data d = new Data();
        d.setTitle(title);
        d.setRating(rating);
        String response = new Gson.toJson(d);
    }
```

return response;
 }

Comment: why not simply returning the `response` variable ?

Comment: problem is not of response, I don't get the values in variables defined in parameter.

Comment: Ok. It was not very clear. I did a response. When you post code, use the button to indent code otherwise the display may be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `@QueryParam` since you don't use the `GET` method but the `POST` method. 
With `POST`, you don't transmit query params with the url but you transmit data  enclosed in the body of the request.

So from the rest controller side, to retrieve the information you can use as parameter your `Data` class if it contains the fields and types of fields matching with sent parameter names and values.

```
@Path("/insert")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String insert(Data data) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
$scope.users = data;
```

instead of this:

```
$scope.users = status;
```

The status is only the response code of the request. Hope this helped)

Comment: The problem is in sending the data not in the recieving.